# Why doesn't this cookie return to the specified path when domain starts with www?

Tags: python, http, cookies, cgi

Cookie works only on a domain without www. prefix. Why?

I want my cookie to be sent to the server when user is on the path identified with a query string.
The path is always the same CGI script.

The problem is that following code works perfectly when the page in question is called as:

http://example.com/cgi-bin/something.py?q=some_query_key

But when it is called as:

http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/something.py?q=some_query_key

then the set cookie doesn't work. I.e. even if some cookie is set, it doesn't come back to server when the page is loaded again.

```
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
import Cookie,
import datetime
import os

def setcookie (q, rated, asked, posted):
    expiration = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=3650)
    cookie = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
    cookie["session"] = "%i:%i:%i" % (rated, asked, posted)
    cookie["session"]["domain"] = "example.com"
    cookie["session"]["path"] = "/cgi-bin/something.py?q="+q
    cookie["session"]["expires"] = expiration.strftime("%a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S P$
    print cookie.output()

rated, asked, posted = (0, 0, 0)
if not os.environ.has_key("HTTP_COOKIE"):
    setcookie("some_query_key", 1, asked, posted)
else:
    cookie = Cookie.SimpleCookie(os.environ["HTTP_COOKIE"])
    rated, asked, posted = map(int, cookie["session"].value.split(":"))
print "Content-Type: text/html\n"
print "<h1>Some HTML, blah blah...</h1><br>"
print "Tuple (rated, asked, posted):", (rated, asked, posted)
```

This is an exemplary code, thus error handling is not included, and fictive domains and paths are used.

Does anyone knows what is happening here. I am on Mozilla Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for bothering everyone.

Adding a dot "." in front of a domain:

```
cookie["session"]["domain"] = ".example.com"
```

does the trick. I knew about the dot prefix, but I didn't know that www is treated as a subdomain even if it is defined in global DNS.

Also, this doesn't make too much sense, as the dot is nowhere mentioned in an URL http://example.com/etc...

Also, My Firefox was confused with much testing, so it wouldn't return it even with dot prefix, because the cookie with a domain prefixed with dot, and one without are considered to be two different cookies, even if they should trigger on same sites. Value of a cookie, i.e. its name of name=value is obviously not evaluated.

Note 1: .example.com will send the cookie for every subdomain of example.com, not only www, so specify the path to control it well.

Note 2: If you do not set the domain attribute of a cookie, browser doesn't set it for subdomains, just for a domain, so, if you want it to work for subdomains, you have to set it.

I decided not to delete this Q but give an A so that others can get some more explanation when they stumble over this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the cookie as `.example.com` instead of `example.com` to be accessible from subdomains.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your A in time, +1 anyway. I tried it alone out of desperation and it worked. BTW, my www. site is not registered as a subdomain, that is why I got totally confused about whole story. My answer is somewhat more extensive, so I'll mark it as accepted instead of yours if something doesn't change. Thanks anyway!